# Mi código no salta linea al momento de ejecutar | C++

Tags: c++, salto-de-linea

Es sobre el calculo de llamadas nacionales, internacionales y locales.
**Mi problema principal es que al momento de ejecutar no salta línea para ingresar los nuevos datos** sino que se queda en donde puse los datos anteriores, el chiste de ese programa es que se haga una tabla de datos pero no se que estoy haciendo mal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>

void gotoxy(int x,int y) {
    HANDLE hcon;
    hcon =GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwPos;
    dwPos.X = x;
    dwPos.Y= y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon,dwPos);
}
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const double I_INITIAL_COST = 7.59;
    const double I_ADDITIONAL_COST = 3.03;
    const double N_INITIAL_COST = 1.20;
    const double N_ADDITIONAL_COST = 0.48;
    const double L_CALL_COST = 0.60;
    const int L_FREE_CALLS = 50;
    const int ROWS = 12;
    
    char tipo[ROWS];
    int duracion[ROWS], R;
    double costo[ROWS];
    double totalCost = 0.0;
    R=1;
    
    // Pedir al usuario los datos de cada llamada
   gotoxy(2,R+2);
   cout << setw(10) << "Tipo"
        << setw(10) << "Duración"
        << setw(10) << "Costo"
        << setw(15) << "Costo Total" << endl << endl;

   // **Me parece que el error puede estar en esta parte**

   for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
      // Ingrese los datos en las columnas correspondientes
      gotoxy(8,R+3); cin >> tipo[i];
      gotoxy(15,R+3); cin >> duracion[i];

        
        // Calcular el costo de la llamada
        double c = 0.0;
        if (tipo[i] == 'I') {
            if (duracion[i] <= 3)
                c = I_INITIAL_COST;
            else
                c = I_INITIAL_COST + (duracion[i] - 3) * I_ADDITIONAL_COST;
        } else if (tipo[i] == 'N') {
            if (duracion[i] <= 3)
                c = N_INITIAL_COST;
            else
                c = N_INITIAL_COST + (duracion[i] - 3) * N_ADDITIONAL_COST;
        } else if (tipo[i] == 'L') {
            if (i < L_FREE_CALLS)
                c = 0.0;
            else
                c = L_CALL_COST;
        }
        
        costo[i] = c;
        totalCost += costo[i];
        
        // Imprimir los datos de la llamada actual
        gotoxy(23,R+3);
        cout << setw(10) << fixed << setprecision(2) << costo[i] << setw(15) << totalCost << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```